# How do I use torch.stack?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

How do I use `torch.stack` to stack two tensors with shapes `a.shape = (2, 3, 4)` and `b.shape = (2, 3)` without an in-place operation?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Stacking requires same number of dimensions. One way would be to unsqueeze and stack. For example:

```
a.size()  # 2, 3, 4
b.size()  # 2, 3
b = torch.unsqueeze(b, dim=2)  # 2, 3, 1
# torch.unsqueeze(b, dim=-1) does the same thing

torch.stack([a, b], dim=2)  # 2, 3, 5
```

Comment: What you want is to use [torch.cat](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.cat) with `unsqueeze` as you've done. [torch.stack](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.stack) creates a NEW dimension, and all provided tensors must be the same size.

Comment: This answer is incorrect with `torch.stack([a, b], dim=2)`, instead you want to use `torch.cat([a,b], dim=2)` as correctly mentioned by @drevicko. `torch.cat` concatenates the sequences in given dimension while `torch.stack` concatenates the sequences in a new dimension, as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54307225/whats-the-difference-between-torch-stack-and-torch-cat-functions/54307331 .

Comment: This won't run. Instead you will receive 
'RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [2, 3, 4] at entry 0 and [2, 3, 1] at entry 1'

Answer (score 20):

Using pytorch 1.2 or 1.4 arjoonn's answer did not work for me.

Instead of `torch.stack` I have used `torch.cat` with pytorch 1.2 and 1.4:

```
>>> import torch
>>> a = torch.randn([2, 3, 4])
>>> b = torch.randn([2, 3])
>>> b = b.unsqueeze(dim=2)
>>> b.shape
torch.Size([2, 3, 1])
>>> torch.cat([a, b], dim=2).shape
torch.Size([2, 3, 5])
```

If you want to use `torch.stack` the dimensions of the tensors have to be the same:

```
>>> a = torch.randn([2, 3, 4])
>>> b = torch.randn([2, 3, 4])
>>> torch.stack([a, b]).shape
torch.Size([2, 2, 3, 4])
```

Here is another example:

```
>>> t = torch.tensor([1, 1, 2])
>>> stacked = torch.stack([t, t, t], dim=0)
>>> t.shape, stacked.shape, stacked

(torch.Size([3]),
 torch.Size([3, 3]),
 tensor([[1, 1, 2],
         [1, 1, 2],
         [1, 1, 2]]))
```

With `stack` you have the `dim` parameter which lets you specify on which dimension you stack the tensors with equal dimensions.

Answer (score 5):

suppose you have two tensors a, b which are equal in dimensions i.e a ( A, B, C) so b (A, B , C)
an example

```
a=torch.randn(2,3,4)
b=torch.randn(2,3,4)
print(a.size())  # 2, 3, 4
print(b.size()) # 2, 3, 4

f=torch.stack([a, b], dim=2)  # 2, 3, 2, 4
f
```

it wont act if they wouldn't be the same dim. Be careful!!