# What's the difference between torch.stack() and torch.cat() functions?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

OpenAI's REINFORCE and actor-critic example for reinforcement learning has the following code:

[REINFORCE](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/reinforcement_learning/reinforce.py):

```
policy_loss = torch.cat(policy_loss).sum()
```

[actor-critic](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/reinforcement_learning/actor_critic.py):

```
loss = torch.stack(policy_losses).sum() + torch.stack(value_losses).sum()
```

One is using [`torch.cat`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cat.html), the other uses [`torch.stack`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.stack.html), for similar use cases.

As far as my understanding goes, the doc doesn't give any clear distinction between them.

**I would be happy to know the differences between the functions.**

Comment: if you are interested in variable length nested lists to tensor here are links that seems to have a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55050717/converting-list-of-tensors-to-tensors-pytorch and https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/nested-list-of-variable-length-to-a-tensor/38699/21

Answer (score 233, accepted):

[`stack`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.stack.html)

> Concatenates sequence of tensors along a **new dimension**.

[`cat`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cat.html)

> Concatenates the given sequence of seq tensors **in the given dimension**.

So if `A` and `B` are of shape (3, 4):

- `torch.cat([A, B], dim=0)` will be of shape (6, 4)
- `torch.stack([A, B], dim=0)` will be of shape (2, 3, 4)

Comment: Thus,    torch.stack([A,B],dim = 0)     is equivalent to     torch.cat([A.unsqueeze(0),b.unsqueeze(0)],dim = 0)   . So if you find yourself doing many unsqueeze() operations before combining tensors you can likely simplify your code using stack().

Comment: Just to complement, in the OpenAI examples in the question, `torch.stack` and `torch.cat` can be used interchangeably in either code line since `torch.stack(tensors).sum() == torch.cat(tensors).sum()`.

Answer (score 39):

```py
t1 = torch.tensor([[1, 2],
                   [3, 4]])

t2 = torch.tensor([[5, 6],
                   [7, 8]])
```

| `torch.stack` | `torch.cat` |
| --- | --- |
| **'Stacks'** a sequence of tensors along a new dimension: [image] | 'Con**cat**enates' a sequence of tensors along an existing dimension: [image] |

These functions are analogous to [`numpy.stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) and [`numpy.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html).

Answer (score 3):

The original answer lacks a good example that is self-contained so here it goes:

```
import torch

# stack vs cat

# cat "extends" a list in the given dimension e.g. adds more rows or columns

x = torch.randn(2, 3)
print(f'{x.size()}')

# add more rows (thus increasing the dimensionality of the column space to 2 -> 6)
xnew_from_cat = torch.cat((x, x, x), 0)
print(f'{xnew_from_cat.size()}')

# add more columns (thus increasing the dimensionality of the row space to 3 -> 9)
xnew_from_cat = torch.cat((x, x, x), 1)
print(f'{xnew_from_cat.size()}')

print()

# stack serves the same role as append in lists. i.e. it doesn't change the original
# vector space but instead adds a new index to the new tensor, so you retain the ability
# get the original tensor you added to the list by indexing in the new dimension
xnew_from_stack = torch.stack((x, x, x, x), 0)
print(f'{xnew_from_stack.size()}')

xnew_from_stack = torch.stack((x, x, x, x), 1)
print(f'{xnew_from_stack.size()}')

xnew_from_stack = torch.stack((x, x, x, x), 2)
print(f'{xnew_from_stack.size()}')

# default appends at the from
xnew_from_stack = torch.stack((x, x, x, x))
print(f'{xnew_from_stack.size()}')

print('I like to think of xnew_from_stack as a \"tensor list\" that you can pop from the front')
```

output:

```
torch.Size([2, 3])
torch.Size([6, 3])
torch.Size([2, 9])
torch.Size([4, 2, 3])
torch.Size([2, 4, 3])
torch.Size([2, 3, 4])
torch.Size([4, 2, 3])
I like to think of xnew_from_stack as a "tensor list"
```

for reference here are the definitions:

> cat: Concatenates the given sequence of seq tensors in the given dimension. The consequence is that a specific dimension changes size e.g. dim=0 then you are adding elements to the row which increases the dimensionality of the column space.

> stack: Concatenates sequence of tensors along a new dimension. I like to think of this as the torch "append" operation since you can index/get your original tensor by "poping it" from the front. With no arguments, it appends tensors to the front of the tensor.

---

Related:

- here is the link from the pytorch forum with discussions on this: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/best-way-to-convert-a-list-to-a-tensor/59949/8 I wish though that `tensor.torch` convert a nested list of tensors to a big tensor with many dimensions that respected the depth of the nested list.

---

## Update: With nested list of the same size

```
def tensorify(lst):
    """
    List must be nested list of tensors (with no varying lengths within a dimension).
    Nested list of nested lengths [D1, D2, ... DN] -> tensor([D1, D2, ..., DN)

    :return: nested list D
    """
    # base case, if the current list is not nested anymore, make it into tensor
    if type(lst[0]) != list:
        if type(lst) == torch.Tensor:
            return lst
        elif type(lst[0]) == torch.Tensor:
            return torch.stack(lst, dim=0)
        else:  # if the elements of lst are floats or something like that
            return torch.tensor(lst)
    current_dimension_i = len(lst)
    for d_i in range(current_dimension_i):
        tensor = tensorify(lst[d_i])
        lst[d_i] = tensor
    # end of loop lst[d_i] = tensor([D_i, ... D_0])
    tensor_lst = torch.stack(lst, dim=0)
    return tensor_lst
```

here is a few unit tests (I didn't write more tests but it worked with my real code so I trust it's fine. Feel free to help me by adding more tests if you want):

```
def test_tensorify():
    t = [1, 2, 3]
    print(tensorify(t).size())
    tt = [t, t, t]
    print(tensorify(tt))
    ttt = [tt, tt, tt]
    print(tensorify(ttt))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_tensorify()
    print('Done\a')
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone is looking into the performance aspects of this, I've done a small experiment. In my case, I needed to convert a list of scalar tensors into a single tensor.

```py
import torch
torch.__version__ # 1.10.2
x = [torch.randn(1) for _ in range(10000)]
torch.cat(x).shape, torch.stack(x).shape # torch.Size([10000]), torch.Size([10000, 1])

%timeit torch.cat(x) # 1.5 ms ± 476 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit torch.cat(x).reshape(-1,1) # 1.95 ms ± 534 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit torch.stack(x) # 5.36 ms ± 643 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

My conclusion is that even if you want to have the additional dimension of `torch.stack`, using `torch.cat` and then `reshape` is better.

**Note:** this post is taken from the PyTorch forum (I am the author of the [original post](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/best-way-to-convert-a-list-to-a-tensor/59949/9?u=rpatrik96))

Comment: That's interesting. Can you explain why that happens? My guess is cache or memory rows are in the `cat` direction and not in the `stack` direction.