# converting list of tensors to tensors pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I have list of tensor where each tensor has a different size. How can I convert this list of tensors into a tensor using PyTorch?

For instance,

```
x[0].size() == torch.Size([4, 8])
x[1].size() == torch.Size([4, 7])  # different shapes!
```

This:

```
torch.tensor(x)
```

Gives the error:

> ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: Please provide more of your code.

Comment: for item in features:
  x.append(torch.tensor((item)))

Comment: this gives me a list of tensors but each tensor have different size so when I try torch.stack(x) it gives me the same error @FábioPerez

Comment: your question need more be detailed...where this data came from, if from image, just resize all image in the same shape, before convert to torch type.

it more easier to anyone here help if you explain it more detailed in processing the data.. at least we can give strategy advise to process the data

Comment: Ran into this problem trying `torch.tensor(torch.split(sometuple))`. Same applies... variable length doesn't work out.

Comment: if you are interested in the case with same lengths here is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54307225/whats-the-difference-between-torch-stack-and-torch-cat-functions/66036075#66036075

Comment: there is also a solution I believe for your question in the pytorch forum also: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/nested-list-of-variable-length-to-a-tensor/38699/21

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You might be looking for [`cat`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.cat).

However, tensors cannot hold variable length data.

for example, here we have a list with two tensors that have different sizes(in their last dim(dim=2)) and we want to create a larger tensor consisting of both of them, so we can use cat and create a larger tensor containing both of their data.

also note that you can't use cat with half tensors on cpu as of [right now](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/16389) so you should convert them to float, do the concatenation and then convert back to half

```
import torch

a = torch.arange(8).reshape(2, 2, 2)
b = torch.arange(12).reshape(2, 2, 3)
my_list = [a, b]
my_tensor = torch.cat([a, b], dim=2)
print(my_tensor.shape) #torch.Size([2, 2, 5])
```

you haven't explained your goal so another option is to use [pad_sequence](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence) like this:

```
from torch.nn.utils.rnn import pad_sequence
a = torch.ones(25, 300)
b = torch.ones(22, 300)
c = torch.ones(15, 300)
pad_sequence([a, b, c]).size() #torch.Size([25, 3, 300])
```

edit: in this particular case, you can use `torch.cat([x.float() for x in sequence], dim=1).half()`

Comment: Hey Separius  thanks for the answer but could u explain what dim is and How should I set it according to?

Comment: also I have a list of tensor sorted  descendly  and the shape of the first tensor is torch.Size([76080, 38])

Comment: the shape of the other tensors would differ in the second element for example the second tensor in the list is  torch.Size([76080, 36])

Comment: when I remove the dim I get this error RuntimeError: _th_cat is not implemented for type torch.HalfTensor

Comment: I tried to use pad sequence but it  gives me this error TypeError: _pack_padded_sequence(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not list

Comment: invalid argument 0: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 0. Got 38 and 36 in dimension  1

Comment: yay... it worked thank u so much so but could u explain what happens that  x.long() because I got a tensor of zeros tensor([[0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0]])

Comment: you have got all zeros? well, that's bad. can you make sure that your initial tensors are not all zeros? you can easily check that via (my_tensor == 0).all()

Comment: damn! :D @OmarAbdelaziz you should use .float() not long(). this will solve your problem, you can also chage the resulting tensor back to half, if you want

Comment: you can do all of these in one line torch.cat([x.float() for x in my_list], dim=1).half()

Comment: @OmarAbdelaziz did it work? if so can you mark my answer as correct?

Comment: there u go here it works thank you very very much ,...... :D <3 I just have one question I know I ask a lot but this is the last one in torch.cat([x.float() for x in my_list], dim=1).half()  what  does .half() do?

Comment: great, glad I helped. cat over a list of float tensors will produce a float tensor, but you were using half(16 bit floating point numbers) to present your data so you can convert this newly created tensor to half withour loosing data

Comment: thank a lot  u can add the torch.cat([x.float() for x in my_list], dim=1).half()  to the answer because it's a great answer

Comment: done! + can you also add some more info to your question so others can benefit? you should mention in your question that you have tensors of different sizes in the second dimension and they are half not float

Comment: not sure if this is useful but here is a solution from the pytorch forum: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/nested-list-of-variable-length-to-a-tensor/38699/21

Answer (score 8):

`Tensor` in pytorch isn't like `List` in python, which could hold variable length of objects.

In pytorch, you can transfer a fixed length array to Tensor:

```py
>>> torch.Tensor([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> tensor([[1., 2.],
            [3., 4.]])
```

Rather than:

```py
>>> torch.Tensor([[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]])
>>> 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-809c707011cc> in <module>
----> 1 torch.Tensor([[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]])

ValueError: expected sequence of length 2 at dim 1 (got 3)
```

And it's same to `torch.stack`.

Comment: Hi cloudyy , thank u for ur answer it's helpful.... but is there any solution if I have different  list of tensors with different lengths to stack then in one tensor

Comment: not sure if this is useful but here is a solution from the pytorch forum: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/nested-list-of-variable-length-to-a-tensor/38699/21

Answer (score 0):

For nested lists of tensors, assuming they'd pass `np.array(x)` (same shape, etc), the following is a performant solution:

```py
def nested_list_to_tensor(x, out_shape, out, top_level=True):
    if isinstance(x[0], list):
        for i in range(out_shape[0]):
            nested_list_to_tensor(x[i], out_shape[1:], out, top_level=False)
    else:
        out.extend(x)
    if top_level:
        return torch.stack(out).reshape(*out_shape)
```

```py
x = [[[torch.randn(2, 8) for _ in range(4)] for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(9)]
out = nested_list_to_tensor(x, (9, 3, 4, 2, 8), [])
print(out.shape)
```

```
torch.Size([9, 3, 4, 2, 8])
```

**Note**: might want to call `.contiguous()` upon `out`, depending on purpose.

#### If `out_shape` is unknown

```py
def get_out_shape(x):
    out_shape = []
    while True:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            out_shape.append(len(x))
            x = x[0]
        else:
            out_shape.extend(list(x.shape))
            break
    return out_shape
```

```py
out = nested_list_to_tensor(x, get_out_shape(x), [])
print(out.shape)
```

#### Alternative

Less performant (esp. on GPU), but maybe more flexible:

```py
def nested_list_to_tensor(x, out):
    if isinstance(x[0], list):
        for i in range(len(out)):
            out[i] = nested_list_to_tensor(x[i], out[i])
    else:
        out = torch.stack(x)
    return out
```

```py
xt = x
while isinstance(xt, list):
    xt = xt[0]
out = torch.zeros(get_out_shape(x), dtype=xt.dtype, layout=xt.layout, 
                  device=xt.device)

out = nested_list_to_tensor(x, out)
print(out.shape)
```

This shouldn't ever need `.contiguous()`.

#### Why performance difference?

Preallocation is generally good, but repeated assignment is expensive, especially on GPU. Appending to a list is much faster, and a single `stack` takes all the concatenation to be done into one big operation.