# Convert a list of tensors to tensors of tensors pytorch

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I have this code:

```py
import torch

list_of_tensors = [ torch.randn(3), torch.randn(3), torch.randn(3)]
tensor_of_tensors = torch.tensor(list_of_tensors)
```

I am getting the error:

> ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars

How can I convert the list of tensors to a tensor of tensors in pytorch?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [converting list of tensors to tensors pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55050717/converting-list-of-tensors-to-tensors-pytorch)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I saw this post, but it does not answer my question
I don't want 1 big tensor, I want a tensor of tensors.

Comment: What is the difference in your opinion between a "tensor of tensors", and an additional dimension in your tensor?

Comment: Using tensor.cat, I will get a tensor of size 9.
I would like to get a tensor of size (3,3)

Comment: Sorry, I sloppily linked to the wrong answer, I apologize. The function you are looking for is [`torch.stack()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.stack), and this has also been answered on Stackoverflow before, although I can't change my duplication vote. See for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54307225/whats-the-difference-between-torch-stack-and-torch-cat-functions). If you need more detail, feel free to respond.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
tensor_of_tensors = torch.stack((list_of_tensors))
print(tensor_of_tensors) #shape (3,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also typecast the torch tensors to NumPy array and then convert them to tensors

```
list_of_tensors = [torch.randn(3).numpy(),torch.randn(3).numpy(),torch.randn(3).numpy()]
tensor_of_tensors = torch.tensor(list_of_tensors)
```