# How to make a list of pytorch tensors in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, tensor

How do I make a list of tensors in Pytorch.
The list should look like this:

```
mylist = [tensor1, tensor2, tensor3]
```

where all the tensors have different shapes

Comment: Well, you just did it.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61359162/convert-a-list-of-tensors-to-tensors-of-tensors-pytorch/66312321#66312321) is a solution you are looking for :

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can instantiate each tensor using pytorch inline or append to a list in a loop.
Inline:

```
mylist = [torch.rand(2), torch.rand(5), torch.rand(1)]
```

In a loop:

```
mylist = [torch.rand(i) for i in range(1, 5)]
```

To create a custom tensor, use `torch.tensor([[1., -1.], [1., -1.]])` for example.
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html