# ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars when using torch.Tensor on list of tensors

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a list of tensors:

```
object_ids = [tensor([2., 3.]), tensor([2., 3.]), tensor([2., 3.]), tensor([2., 3.]), tensor([2., 3.]), tensor([2., 3.]), tensor([2., 3.]), tensor([2., 3.]), tensor([2., 3.]), tensor([2., 3.])]
```

Intuitively, it seems like I should be able to create a new tensor from this:

```
torch.as_tensor(object_ids, dtype=torch.float32)
```

But this does NOT work. Apparently, torch.as_tensor and torch.Tensor can only turn lists of **scalars** into new tensors. it cannot turn a list of d-dim tensors into a d+1 dim tensor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a list of tensors to tensors of tensors pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61359162/convert-a-list-of-tensors-to-tensors-of-tensors-pytorch)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`torch.stack`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.stack.html).

In your example:

```
>>> object_ids = [tensor([2., 3.]), tensor([2., 3.]), tensor([2., 3.]), tensor([2., 3.]), tensor([2., 3.]), tensor([2., 3.]), tensor([2., 3.]), tensor([2., 3.]), tensor([2., 3.]), tensor([2., 3.])]
>>> torch.stack(object_ids)
tensor([[2., 3.],
        [2., 3.],
        [2., 3.],
        [2., 3.],
        [2., 3.],
        [2., 3.],
        [2., 3.],
        [2., 3.],
        [2., 3.],
        [2., 3.]])
```