# Convert list of tensors into tensor pytorch

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I have a list of embeddings. The list has `N` lists with `M` embedding (tensors) each.

```
list_embd = [[M embeddings], [M embeddings], ...]
```

(Each embedding is a `tensor with size (1,512)`)

What I want to do is create a `tensor size (N, M)`, where each `"cell"` is one embedding.

Tried this for numpy array.

```
array = np.zeros(n,m)

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        array[i, j] = list_embd[i][j]
```

But still got errors.

In pytorch tried to `concat` all M embeddings into one tensor size (1, M), and then concat all rows. But when I concat along dim 1 two of those M embeddings, I get a tensor shaped (1, 1028) instead (1, 2).

```
final = torch.tensor([])
    for i in range(n):
        interm = torch.tensor([])
        for j in range(m):
            interm = torch.cat((interm, list_embd[i][j]), 0)
        final = = torch.cat((final, interm), 1)
```

Any ideas or suggestions?
I need a matrix with the embeddings in each cell.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a list of tensors to tensors of tensors pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61359162/convert-a-list-of-tensors-to-tensors-of-tensors-pytorch)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`torch.cat`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cat.html#torch.cat) and [`torch.stack`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.stack.html#torch.stack) to create a `final` 3D tensor of shape `(N, M, 512)`:

```py
final = torch.stack([torch.cat(sub_list, dim=0) for sub_list in list_embd], dim=0)
```

First, you use `torch.cat` to create a list of `N` 2D tensors of shape `(M, 512)` from each list of `M` embeddings. Then `torch.stack` is used to stack these `N` 2D matrices into a single 3D tensor `final`.