# How can I add an element to a PyTorch tensor along a certain dimension?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have a tensor `inps`, which has a size of `[64, 161, 1]` and I have some new data `d` which has a size of `[64, 161]`. How can I add `d` to `inps` such that the new size is `[64, 161, 2]`?

Comment: As a side note, I could not find an answer that actually goes about the problem in exactly the same way, although this is a very common issue. Feel free to link to a duplicate question if you can find one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a cleaner way by using `.unsqueeze()` and `torch.cat()`, which makes direct use of the PyTorch interface:

```py
import torch

# create two sample vectors
inps = torch.randn([64, 161, 1])
d = torch.randn([64, 161])

# bring d into the same format, and then concatenate tensors
new_inps = torch.cat((inps, d.unsqueeze(2)), dim=-1)
print(new_inps.shape)  # [64, 161, 2]
```

Essentially, unsqueezing the second dimension already brings the two tensors into the same shape; you just have to be careful to unsqueeze along the right dimension.
Similarly, the [concatenation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.cat) is unfortunately named differently from the otherwise similarly named NumPy function, but behave the same. Note that instead of letting `torch.cat` figure out the dimension by providing `dim=-1`, you can also explicitly provide the dimension to concatenate along, in this case by replacing it with `dim=2`.

Keep in mind the [difference between concatenation and stacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54307225/whats-the-difference-between-torch-stack-and-torch-cat-functions), which is helpful for similar problems with tensor dimensions.

Comment: Changing `2` to `-1` would make it more generic if you know it is always the last dimension. Also, I don't know why, I prefer `d[..., None]` than using `unsqueeze` :)

Comment: Good catch! I rarely use it myself (mostly for explicit clarity of what dimension is altered, but for the sake of generality, I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have to first reshape `d` so that it has a third dimension along which concatenation becomes possible. After it has a third dimension and the two tensors have the same number of dimensions, then you can use torch.cat((inps, d),2) to stack them.

```
old_shape = tuple(d.shape)
new_shape = old_shape + (1,)
inps_new = torch.cat( (inps, d.view( new_shape ), 2)
```

Comment: Can I also use `unsqueeze`?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can achieve this by squeezing the larger tensor and stacking:

```py
inps = torch.randn([64, 161, 1])
d = torch.randn([64, 161])

res = torch.stack((inps.squeeze(), d), dim=-1)

res.shape
>>> [64, 161, 2]
```