# Appending zero rows to a 2D Tensor in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, zero-padding

Suppose I have a tensor 2D tensor `x` of shape `(n,m)`. How can I extend the first dimension of the tensor by appending zero rows in `x` by specifying the indices of where the zero rows will be located in the resulting tensor? For a concrete example:

```
x = torch.tensor([[1,1,1],
                  [2,2,2],
                  [3,3,3],
                  [4,4,4]])
```

And I want to append 2 zero rows such that their row-index will be 1,3, respectively, in the resulting tensor? I.e. in the example the result would be

```
X = torch.tensor([1,1,1],
                 [0,0,0],
                 [2,2,2],
                 [0,0,0],
                 [3,3,3],
                 [4,4,4]])
```

I tried using `F.pad` and `reshape`.

Comment: Can you use `NumPy` and then convert the result to a tensor again?

Comment: No unfortunately. I needed as an intermediate operation for training a NN.

Comment: You can do this like this with `numpy` in one line : `torch.tensor(np.insert(x.numpy(), (1, 3), np.zeros((1, x.shape[1])), axis=0))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`torch.tensor.index_add_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.index_add_.html).

```
import torch

zero_index = [1, 3]
size = (6, 3)

x = torch.tensor([[1,1,1],
                  [2,2,2],
                  [3,3,3],
                  [4,4,4]])

t = torch.zeros(size, dtype=torch.int64)
index = torch.tensor([i for i in range(size[0]) if i not in zero_index])
# index -> tensor([0, 2, 4, 5])

t.index_add_(0, index, x)
print(t)
```

Output:

```
tensor([[1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `torch.cat`:

```
def insert_zeros(x, all_j):
    zeros_ = torch.zeros_like(x[:1])
    pieces = []
    i      = 0
    for j in all_j + [len(x)]:
        pieces.extend([x[i:j],
                       zeros_])
        i = j
    return torch.cat(pieces[:-1],
                      dim=0     )

# insert_zeros(x, [1,2])
# tensor([[1, 1, 1],
#         [0, 0, 0],
#         [2, 2, 2],
#         [0, 0, 0],
#         [3, 3, 3],
#         [4, 4, 4]])
```

This code is compatible with backpropagation, since the tensors are not modified in-place.

---

More information:
[What's the difference between torch.stack() and torch.cat()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54307225/whats-the-difference-between-torch-stack-and-torch-cat)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Ideally I would like to this more generic. Suppose the indices `[1,2]` is a given sequence with `n` elements. Then this approach cannot be generalized easily.

Comment: Hi, I edited my solution. Now it is compatible with `n` insertion elements. Cheers,