# classification using 4-channel images in pytorch

Tags: classification, pytorch

I have some gray scale and color images with label. I want to combine this gray and color images (4-channel) and run transfer learning using 4-channel images. How to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use torch.stack function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52288635/how-to-use-torch-stack-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you want to combine 1 channel images and 3 channel images and get a 4 channel image and use this as your input.

If this is what you want to do you can just use torch.cat().

Some example code of loading two images and combining them along the channel dimension

```
import numpy as np
import torch
from PIL import Image

image_rgb = Image.open(path_to_rgb_image)
image_rgb_tensor = torch.from_numpy(np.array(image_rgb))
image_rgb.close()

image_grayscale = Image.open(path_to_grayscale_image))
image_grayscale_tensor = troch.from_numpy(np.array(image_grayscale))
image_grayscale.close()

image_input = torch.cat([image_rgb_tensor, image_grayscale_tensor], dim=2)
```

I assumed that the grayscale image you want to use translated to a tensor with the shape `[..., ..., 1]` and the rgb image to `[..., ..., 3]`.

Answer (score -1):

your current model expects an RGB input with only three channels, thus its first conv layer has `in_channels=3` and the shape of this first layer's `weight` is `out_channels`x**3**x`kernel_height`x`kernel_width`.
In order to accommodate 4 channel input, you need to change the first layer to have `in_channels=4` and a `weight` of shape `out_channels`x**4**x`kernel_height`x`kernel_width`. You also want to preserve the learned weights, so you should initialize the new `weight` to be the same as the old except for tiny noise in the added weights.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my question is how I will combine gray and color image in dataloader?